# Convert YYYYMMDD date format and Calculate Industry average by date

Tags: sql, sas

i connected using

```
proc sql; 
connect to odbc as odbc("......"); 
create table work.market as select distinct * from connection to odbc( 
select distinct C.Product#, A.county, B.DT, profit2, Rev2)

From Mtable.duv A, Ttable.duv B, otable C
Where B.Product# = C.Product#
and   B.Product# = A.Product#

and   B.Dt = C.Dt
and   B.dt between A.dt_start and dt_end
and   B.dt between 20140331 and 20170630
);
disconnect from odbc;
quit;

data work.smallmarket;
set work.market;
where country=Nigeria;
NetMargin=profit2/Rev2;
keep Product# NetMargin DT;
run;
```

1) if DT is my date, how do I change the date format from YYYYMMDD to a SAS date format like 01Jan1960? When I run the above I get my data but the dates come out as 20170630 for example. How can i convert by date column to show in the format 30Jun2017. I posted how I got my initial data set "work.market" just in case that is part of the issue. Sorry can't post the log. Can you please help?

Comment: Include the log from that code please, it doesn't look correct at all. Your code shown also has nothing to do with your questions. Can you post what you've tried related to your question and what your data looks like?

Comment: The first question is fine I think the way you have it.  The second you need to ask separately, and as Reeza notes you need to show what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to a SAS date format, you have two places to do that.

First, you can do it in the `create table` statement; that is a SAS statement, not a SQL Server/whatever statement.

```
proc sql; 
connect to odbc as odbc("......"); 
create table work.market as select Product#, county, dt format=date9.,profit2, rev2
  from connection to odbc( 
select distinct Product#, county, DT, profit2, Rev2);
```

The second place you can do it is in the data step following.

```
data work.smallmarket;
set work.market;
where country=Nigeria;
format dt date9.;
NetMargin=profit2/Rev2;
keep Product# NetMargin DT;
run;
```